# PDF-XChange Editor is stuck print process of 0% when trying to print

Tags: pdf, printing, network-printers

it happens sometimes.

my printer is all Good.

my network is all Good.

I tried other programs to print it all worked.

why my PDF-XChange Editor is sick

i need some infomation or reasion why it happen.

Thank you all for infomation.